# Drawing lines on a Ternary Plot

Tags: r

I have a ternary plot that I'm generating like this:

```
library(vcd)
ternaryplot(abs(replicate(3, rnorm(50))), grid=FALSE)
```

I don't like the built-in grid so I disabled it, but I want to draw some lines of my own: specifically I want to draw a line from each point of my triangle to the midpoint of the opposite face (i.e. three lines bisecting my triangle and crossing at the center) and I can't quite figure out how to do this. I tried `abline()` but nothing seems to happen when I do.

How can I draw lines on this plot?

Comment: I am not sure if this helps, but I got yesterday an answer to my 1.5 years old question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439123/making-a-tenary-plot/20553475?noredirect=1#20553475) pointing me to http://ggtern.com/ This looks very promising.

Comment: @Beasterfield funny that! I used ternaryplot based on the answers to your question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this. Most of it I gathered from reading the code for `ternaryplot`:

```
library(vcd)
ternaryplot(abs(replicate(3, rnorm(50))), grid=FALSE)

top <- sqrt(3)/2
xlim <- c(-0.03, 1.03)
ylim <- c(-1, top)
pushViewport(viewport(width = unit(1, "snpc")))
pushViewport(viewport(width = 0.8, height = 0.8, xscale = xlim, 
                      yscale = ylim, name = "plot"))
grid.lines(c(0.75, 0.00), c(0.5 * top, 0))
grid.lines(c(0.25, 1.00), c(0.5 * top, 0))
grid.lines(c(0.50, 0.50), c(1.0 * top, 0))
upViewport(2)
```

[image]

Comment: this is very nice. One question, how would you adjust the line thickness for (1) gridlines, (2) border, (3) open symbol, for example pch=2 (open triangle)?

Answer (score 5):

Using the [ggtern](http://www.ggtern.com) package which I have recently published on CRAN, the following can be achieved:

[image: Output]

Which can be produced with the following code:

```
library(ggtern)
DATA <- data.frame(x = c(1,0,0),
                   y = c(0,1,0),
                   z = c(0,0,1),
                   xend = c(0,.5,.5),
                   yend = c(.5,0,.5),
                   zend = c(.5,.5,0),
                   Series = c("yz","xz","xy"))
ggtern(data=DATA,aes(x,y,z,xend=xend,yend=yend,zend=zend)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(color=Series),size=1) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("darkgreen","darkblue","darkred")) +
  theme_bw() + theme_nogrid() + 
  theme(legend.position=c(0,1),legend.justification=c(0,1)) + 
  labs(title = "Sample Midpoint Segments")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version, ggtern 2.0.1, there is now a couple of new geometries to make isoproportion lines, here is an example:

[image: solution]

```
#Demonstrate the isoprop geometries
df   = data.frame(x=1,y=1,z=1)
ggtern(data=df,aes(x,y,z)) + geom_point() +
  geom_Tisoprop(value=seq(0,1,by=0.25),colour='darkred') +
  geom_Lisoprop(value=c(.5),colour='darkgreen') +
  geom_Risoprop(value=c(.5),colour='darkblue') +
  theme_minimal()
```