# ggtern error - Error in f(..., self = self) : unused argument (plot$coordinates)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

Why I am getting this error? I have even tried a simple mock example below but still getting the error. Link for the mock example - [Making a ternary plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439123/making-a-ternary-plot)

```
x  <- data.frame(
  x1 = c( 0, 0, 1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.2 ),
  x2 = c( 0, 1, 0, 0.3, 0.2, 0.8 ),
  x3 = c( 1, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.2, 0.0 )
)

library(ggtern)
ggtern(data=x,aes(x1,x2,x3)) + 
  geom_point(fill="red",shape=21,size=4)
```

Getting the following error:

> Error in f(..., self = self) : unused argument (plot$coordinates)

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade to the previous version of ggplot2 (2.2.1). [solution](https://bitbucket.org/nicholasehamilton/ggtern/issues/4/error-running-the-ggtern-examples)