# Assignability diagrams - plotting probability of belonging to three groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to plot an "assignability plot" in which the probability of belonging to three groups is shown on a triangle with dot as each observation. The center of the triangle  will represent observations with equal probability (which is 33%) to belonging to each of the three groups (`Group1_prob`, `Group2_Prob`, `Group3_Prob`), and other areas in the triangle will represent varying degrees of group membership. These observations or dots have colours according to `Another_category`.

I have generated a random dataset with variables I have mentioned above to clarify:

```
s <- seq(1, 100, 1)
a1 <- matrix(rbeta(100*3,2,2), nc=3)
a1 <- sweep(a1, 1, rowSums(a1), FUN="/")
category2 <- sample(c(1,2,3), 100, replace = TRUE)

df = data.frame(s, a1, category2)

colnames(df) <- c('observation', 'Group1_prob', 'Group2_prob', 'Group3_prob', 'Another_category')
```

The data frame will look something like the below:

```
observation Group1_prob Group2_prob Group3_prob Another_category
1   0.20692290  0.5259100   0.2671671   1
2   0.32271247  0.4352754   0.2420121   3
3   0.26894997  0.2367609   0.4942891   2
4   0.51197553  0.2400177   0.2480067   3
5   0.29448485  0.3002781   0.4052370   2
6   0.39686890  0.1370191   0.4661120   2
7   0.33881746  0.2946256   0.3665570   3
8   0.36083040  0.3123024   0.3268672   1
9   0.05739799  0.1207381   0.8218639   3
```

Would this be at all possible with `ggplot2` in R?

A  *Nature Communications* [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-05892-0/figures/5) by Young et al shows this plot perfectly:

[image: Assignability plot]

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439123/making-a-ternary-plot

Comment: It turned out to be really hard question for me, tried to conceptualize it with vectors as if it is like a physics question but all vectors are co-dependent. I mean, can someone give a link or reference for the math behind it? I am very curious.

Comment: @eonurk the paper accompanying the ggtern package might be helpful: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v087c03

Comment: thank you! I was being lazy not searching for it though.